# Google translate says that both sentences are correct, so which one should I use?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> If I **would have known** you were sick, I would have brought you some meals.

Or.

> If I **had known** you were sick, I would have brought you some meals.

For example that.

Comment: There is no reason to include _would have_ in the first clause to express the meaning you intend.

Comment: "If I would have known you were sick" - NO! NO! NO!

Comment: This might help explain why Google translate is not infallible, although it is constantly improving: [Natural language processing aka NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

Comment: To the close voters, please don't confuse ELL with EL&U standards. The OP is still a newcomer, so give the person some slack. Besides, their  research is *Google Translate*!

Comment: You might be interested in my question [“If I would have lost you” vs “If I had lost you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/) as asked years ago on ELU. I've almost *never* heard your *(**non-contracted**)* first version from BrE speakers, but it's not uncommon with non-Anglophone North Europeans, and I sometimes hear it from Americans. Most Brits only use it as the contracted ***If I'd have known...*** - and like me, many of them would "unpack" that as *If I **had have** known...* (regardless of the grammarians' horrified squawks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I fear that you sometimes misjudge common parlance in your own country. You're constantly on about "we don't say this or that". I'd say that the class/education divide in the UK is as great as in US. You're just not going to right pubs.

Comment: @Lambie: My father "escaped" from a poverty-stricken Lancashire pit village, and my mother was spawned by Irish bog-trotters, so we're definitely a family of peasants. But all five of the children got degrees, which would have been inconceivable [***if we'd have been born***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+i%27d+have+been+born%22) a couple of decades earlier. I don't know about the class / education divide in the US (I thought you guys had a ***wealth*** / education divide), but that divide in the UK is far less today than it was when I was born.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I mean class/education. Percentage-wise, as many people speak English marked by education or not, on both sides of the pond. The prevalence of something like "If you would have known (or would've have known)" here seems greater because there are more people and more media, innit?

Answer (score 4):

Google translate doesn't check grammar, it attempts to produce translations of whatever it is given, and if it is given ungrammatical English, it attempts to translate them, but translations of ungrammatical language is "undefined behaviour" as 'C' programmers say.  So the fact that Google translates ungrammatical English to grammatical Russian (or other language) proves nothing.

The counterfactual "third conditional" form uses the past perfect for the if-clause, and the conditional form with "would" for the conclusion.  You don't use the conditional "would" in the if-clause.

So only the second is correct. It means that "I did not know you were sick but..."

Comment: Note that both should be understandable in context.

Comment: So far as I know, Google Translate is powered by neural net technology - which means it's effectively not "programmed" at all. And I very much doubt anyone has ever attempted to train a neural net to distinguish between "grammatical" and "ungrammatical", because it would be prohibitively expensive to create sufficient training data (in the unlikely event that a quorum of grammarians could be identified who all agreed on what is or isn't "grammatical" in the first place). So the point about "undefined behaviour" doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 2):

*If I would have known* is a non-standard form which is fairly common, particularly in the US.

The GloWbE corpus ("Global Web-based English") shows the following counts

> *If I had known*: 593 total (152 US, 143 GB, 43 CA, 40 IE, 33 AU)

> *If I would have known*: 51 total (US 29, GB 6, CA 5)

So in that corpus, *If I would have known* occurs only 1/12 as often as *If I had known*, and more than half the instances of the non-standard form are from US sources.

Comment: Does your corpus search distinguish (or allow *you* to distinguish) between *If **I would** have known...* and the contracted form *If **I'd** have known...*? I have no problem at all with the contracted version (which to me only becomes "non-standard" when I "unpack" ***I'd*** to ***I had*** rather than ***I would***).

Comment: If + would like that is definitely hoi polloi. Sorry, but true. It's like all the people in my town who say She don't and He don't. I don't judge them for it at all. Some of them are charming. But as a listener, it tells me something about their class and educational background. People forget how HUGE the US is, so it's easy to think (from the media, etc.) that it's more widespread than, say, an equivalent class and education difference in the UK.

Comment: [One of the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you#comment341056_62490) under Prof John Lawler's answer to my question about this on ELU says *I'm in the Midwestern US as well, and **I hear people say "If you would have…" pretty frequently**, with the word "would" fully pronounced: /ˌɪfjəˈwʊdə/.* I kinda doubt the poster there thinks of himself as somehow "substandard" in terms of class or education! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would no more use _if I'd have known_ than I would _if I would have known_. I acknowledge that other people use both, though. Not got time at present to check the corpus, but I'll do so later if I remember.

Comment: John Lawler doesn't explicitly say he personally uses the contracted form **/ɪfaydə'lɔstyu/**, but I think that's implied in the linked answer. And he says he "unpacks" that to **If I had lost you** - completely ignoring the schwa in the phonetic transcription. While the rest of us argue about whether that schwa represents **have**, John seems to just dismiss it as some kind of "artefact".

Comment: I tried to check "If I'd have known" on the GloWbE corpus (which requires you to separate "I'd" into two words "I" and "'d", and it reports an error.